# How to create Apollo Client read function to read a field from a nested object

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-cache-inmemory

I need to distinguish between two queries with the same __typename (Union) to get Apollo Client typePolicies cache to work properly.

So `RelatedNodes` is a Union and I don't get a unique identifier field from the server.

The `nodes` are differentiated by a field called `type`. See the query:

```
query GetNodesTypeOne($limit: Int, $offset: Int,) {
  getNodesTypeOne(limit: $limit, offset: $offset) {
    __typename
    nodes {
      uuid
      type
      title
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use that field `nodes.type` to create a unique identifier, which I can use in the `keyFields` property (like `keyFields: ['type']`).

The Apollo Client `typePolicies` configured like:

```
typePolicies: {
    RelatedNodes: {
      keyFields: [],
      fields: {
        nodes: offsetLimitPagination(),
      },
    },
  },
```

What I am trying:

Adding a [local only field](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/managing-state-with-field-policies/) to my query:

```
   query GetNodesTypeOne($limit: Int, $offset: Int,) {
      getNodesTypeOne(limit: $limit, offset: $offset) {
        type @client // the field a want to use in the typePolicies
        nodes {
          uuid
          type
          title
        }
      }
    }
```

Then with Apollo Client [read function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/#the-read-function), I want to create a `type` field which gets it 's value from `nodes.type`?

Is that possible?

Comment: Hi meez, I am facing a similar issue at the moment. Did you find a solution for this?